# Error uploading video on YouTube using YouTube API

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("youtube", "developer key", "ID", "PAswd");
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

    Video newVideo = new Video();

    newVideo.Title = txttitle.Text.Trim();
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
    newVideo.Keywords = txtkeyword.Text.Trim();
    newVideo.Description = txtdesc.Text.Trim();
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\AVISample.avi", "video/quicktime");

    Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
}
```

It's taking too much time to upload a 2MB file and showing this error:

> Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

Comment: I don't see anything specifically wrong with your code. You say that it takes "too much time" to upload, but that's really dependent on the speed of your Internet connection—the YouTube API servers don't throttle upload speed. If you suspect there's a bug with the .NET client library related to that other error, please report it at http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/list

Comment: My code looks exactly like yours and I am getting the same error. Did you ever resolve this? thx